# Insert image directly without featured image in wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress

In my blogs home page, where all the posts are listed shows posts with featured images that I've added while posting. The quality of featured images are too bad. It didn't improve much even after increasing image quality or image size. But after going to a post, the image is just fine.

Now, I want to show the images in my home page's post list as it is displayed in the individual post. That is, I don't want wordpress make featured image of my posts and show them exactly as I upload them.

My blogs address is, [www.gadgetshift.com](http://www.gadgetshift.com)

Compare this with [www.bgr.com](http://www.bgr.com) Their home page images are very high quality and looks exactly as inside the post.

If you go to this address, you would realize my problem. Some featured images are blurred. But inside the post, it shows correctly.

Please help me guys with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to resole this problem , try to select "full image" when selecting featured image in Admin Panel , this should help increase the quality of the image

Comment: Hi RedhopIT,
I've tried it. But please see this site, www.bgr.com
Here, the home page images are very high quality and looks exactly as inside the posts. I'm finding how they have done it.

Thanks for your reply.